# Null reference using Linq to Xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am making Country, state dropdownlist.

for eg: For particular country, i will read states of that country from XML file below is my code

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         string  st = (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex).ToString();

         XDocument main = XDocument.Load((Server.MapPath(@"XMLFile1.xml")));


    var query = from user in main.Descendants("country")
            where st == user.Element("state").Value --//i am getting an error here like object 
            select user;                                reference not set to an instance object

    DropDownList2.DataSource = query;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();   

    }
```

OP's XML (link provided in Chuck's comments) : [bind dropdownlist using XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224655/bind-dropdownlist-using-xml)

Answer (score 2):

If you using a namespace in your xml file then the following might help you.:

```
XNamespace ns = "url";// the url is the namespace path for your namespace
var query = from user in main.Descendants("country")
            from state in user.Elements("state")
            where state.Value == "st"
            select user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your XML, but the current problem is that a user doesn't have a child  `.Element("state")` and therefore you are trying to reference `null.Value` for that user.

This Xml library can help you with that: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/

With the following code you can get the item you need.

```
string country = "Sri Lanka";
XElement root = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(@"XMLFile1.xml"));
XElement xcountry = root.XPathElement("//country[.={0}]", country);
```

Or

```
XElement xcountry = root.Descendants("country")
            .FirstOrDefault(user => user.Value == country);
```

Then

```
XElement state = (XElement)xcountry.NextNode;
string[] states = state.Elements("text").Select(xtext => xtext.Value).ToArray();
```

Then you probably bind states as your data source.

Comment: how can i enter my xml here??

Comment: Add it to your post, click the grey `edit` link at the bottom of your post.

Comment: i am unable to add the xml file it is showing some error you can check my xml as same as in this link    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224655/bind-dropdownlist-using-xml

Comment: @CédricRup those are not child nodes, they are following nodes.  Yuck!

Comment: @user1435482 What is it you want your query to return, the list of states or the country that has the state?

Comment: @ChuckSavage when i select the country in one DDL the second DDL have to populate the corresponding states in the country

Comment: @ChuckSavage do i have any problem with my xml?? or is it fine?

Comment: @user1435482 It can be used, though it would work easier if the state element was a child of the country.

Comment: @user1435482 Having state element outside country element makes little sense

Comment: @user1435482 Adjusted my answer for your current Xml

Comment: @ChuckSavage i have changed the code as u said and i am getting same error at  XElement xcountry = main.Descendants("country")
                 .FirstOrDefault(user => user.Value == "country");
             XElement query = (XElement)xcountry.NextNode; //here

Comment: @user1435482 Not "country", but country, let me edit to show you what country should be.  I had it in my testing, and it works.

Comment: @ChuckSavage when i use country i am getting an error like --The name 'country' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you'd better use a "SelectMany" solution to avoid checking presence of nodes

```
 var query = from user in main.Descendants("country")
            from state in user.Elements("state")
            where state.Value == st
            select user;
```

users.Elements("state") will be empty (not null) if the node does not exists, and so the user node will not be included in the where clause

100% pure Linq, works without default values

Edit : taking new info from xml shape in Chuck's answer comments, the request should probably be

```
 var query = from user in main.Descendants("country")
            from state in user.Elements("state")
            from text in state.Elements("text")
            where text.Value == st
            select user;
```

Edit 2 : my bad, the xml in not fully hierarchical...

Comment: Rup i have tried your code but i am unable to get the corresponding states in the dropdown